# HQL Problem

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi every one I have these classe

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username_fk"})})
public class Login implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "password", length = 64)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "roles", length = 32)
    private String roles;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username_fk", nullable=false)
    private Branch branch;
    //some getter and sette
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "branch", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"bname", "branch_fk"})})
public class Branch implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "username", length = 64, nullable=false)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "bname", length = 64)
    private String branchName;
    @Column(name = "officername", length = 64)
    private String officerName;
    @Column(name = "studcount")
    private int studCount;
    @Column(name = "blevel", columnDefinition="int default 0")
    private int level;
    @Column(name = "officeremail", length = 64)
    private String officerEmail;   
    @Column(name = "confirmed", columnDefinition = "tinyint default 0")
    private int confirmed;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "branch", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Login login;
```

when i use this Query :

```
executeQuery("select l from Login as l inner join l.branch as b where l.branch.bname = ?", username)
```

or this:

```
executeQuery("select b.login from Branch b where b.username = ?", username)
```

I have get this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bname of: Data.Entity.Branch
```

but when use this code:

```
executeQuery("select b.login from Branch b where b.id = ?", username)
it's return correct result
```

I means this type of HQL just work for Primary key? or my maping have problem?
is there any way that I can use other field(except Primary Key) form joinable table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate expects you to use the property name instead of the database column name, i.e. `branchName` insted of `bname` and `userName` instead of `username`.

So if you change your queries to

```
executeQuery("select l from Login as l inner join l.branch as b " +
     "where l.branch.branchName  = ?",
     username);
```

and

```
executeQuery("select b.login from Branch b where b.userName = ?", username);
```

, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Tanx Man :P
I am newbie In Hibernate and don't know many things
Tanx for your fast answer